# Angular website problem with Azure on page reload

Tags: angular, azure

Problem: whenever I reload any page except main I get 404 Not Found error. It happens only on Azure (local host works fine).
I am using Angular 5.
Here is what browser shows me on page reload:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Website url: http://learnwithmentor.azurewebsites.net/

Web.config: https://github.com/ss-ita/learnwithmentor-server/blob/master/LearnWithMentor/Web.config

Comment: can you post the content of your web.config

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Angular routes, right? You need to add some URL rewrites because IIS is currently checking if the file or directory your URL points to exists. And since they don't it gives you an error message.

This goes into your `web.config` under `system.webServer`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```